# Automatically handling single vs multiple rows with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I'm still learning SQLAlchemy so I apologize if I'm looking at this entirely wrong (or use the wrong terminology), but if I understand correctly, if I query a table that has multiple rows I will need to iterate through the object that is returned to access each row's data, whereas if just one row exists in the table, I don't need to iterate through the object and can access the column names directly.  For example (hopefully I'm doing this right):

```
# when multiple records exist
records = session.query(Customer).all()
for row in records:
    print(row.name)
```

vs

```
# when a single record exists
records = session.query(Customer).all() 
print(records.name)
```

What doesn't seem to make sense to me is that I need to write two different methods to access the data depending on whether one or more rows is returned.  That just seems weird, in addition to the fact that I can't easily find out how many rows are in the returned recordset such such that I can act upon the data accordingly.  Is there something I'm missing?  Is there a single method that I can use to access data that was returned from the query regardless of whether there's one or more rows in the DB?

Thanks!
Mike

Comment: If you use query .all() to get data one or more you still must loop the data. If you query to get one row you can use `.first()` or `.one()` and without loop you can get data.

Comment: Ohhhh!!  Yes!  That was it!  I was mixing up using .first() and .all() with a limit and that was getting me all confused.  So I pretty need to know if I'm calling a function that's using .first() and anticipate that its return value won't be an iterable.  Thanks for the clarification - this was driving me NUTS!

Comment: Ok, If my question is correct or can help you. I will answer your question in box. Please approved. Thanks Mike.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use query `.all()` to get data one or more you still must loop the data. If you query to get only one row you can use `.first()` or `.one()` and without loop you can get data.

Comment: Yeah, for some reason I didn't see that in the docs and it was really confusing me.  Thanks again for your help.